# Авторизация в Php

Tags: php, debian, mysql

Доброго всем дня!В очередной раз нуждаюсь в помощи участников форума!Проблема в следующем:
есть два скрипта auth.php и cabinet.php, собственно суть работы предельно проста auth.php при успешной авторизации бросает нас в cabinet.php,но почему то это не срабатывает( А именно:авторизация проходит успешно,а вот вместо cabinet.php я попадаю обратно на страничку авторизации,есть подозрение что переменные $login и $pass не передаются скрипту cabinet.php,но вот почему?

***UPDATE:***
**Сервер на Debian**

**На серваке с FreeBSD эти же скрипты работают,может что-то с конфигурацией php не то?**

***UPDATE №2:***

**Вот что пишет в логе:**

[error] [client ip_adress] PHP Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /var/www/cabinet.php on line 11, referer: http://трали-вали.ру/auth.php 
[error] [client ip_adress] PHP Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /var/www/cabinet.php on line 11, referer: http://трали-вали.ру/auth.php
 [client ip_adress] PHP Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /var/www/cabinet.php on line 11, referer: http://трали-вали.ру /auth.php 
 [client ip_adress] PHP Notice: Undefined index: sbm_auth in /var/www/auth.php on line 11, referer: http://трали-вали.ру/auth.php 

Ниже привожу код с обоих скриптов

auth.php:

```
\\auth.php
$host='localhost';
$database='family';
$user='root'; 
$pswd='пароль к базе';
$dbh=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pswd) or die ("I can not be connected to MYSQL.");
mysql_select_db($database) or die ("I can not be connected to base.");

if($_POST['sbm_auth'])
   {
   $login=($_POST['login']);
   $pass=($_POST['pass']);

$check_q=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='".
    $login."' AND pass='".$pass."'");

if(mysql_num_rows($check_q) === 1)
    {
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
    $_SESSION['usr_id'] = md5(crypt($login,$pass));
    header("Location: cabinet.php");
    }
    else
    {
    echo "incorrect login or password";
    }
    }
print("<CENTER>");
echo '<form action="" method="POST">
<table>
<tr><td>LOGIN</td> <td><input type="text" name="login"></td></tr>
<tr><td>PASSWORD</td> <td><input type="password" name="pass"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2 align=center><input type="submit" name="sbm_auth" value="ENTER"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>';
print("</CENTER>");
```

cabinet.php:

```
\\cabinet.php
if(isset($_REQUEST[session_name()]))
{
    session_start();
}
else
{
    header("Location: auth.php");
}

if($_SESSION['usr_id'] == md5(crypt($_SESSION['login'],$_SESSION['pass'])))
{
    echo "HELLO";
}
else
{
header("Location: auth.php");
}
```

Comment: А вот такую [штуку](http://programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=39491) читали?

Comment: Спасибо,прочёл.Только вот беда,что окончательного ответа там так и не получено,а предложенное возможное решение мне не помогло...

Comment: А какое из решений вы использовали?

Comment: В смысле, что дает вот такой код `echo ini_get("session.use_cookies") . " and "  . ini_get("session.use_trans_sid") . "<br><br>";`

Comment: 0 and 1<br>
А толку от этого 0)))

Comment: Ну так у вас оно и работать не будет. Первая должна быть единица, чтобы сессия передавалась через куки. А в вашем случае сессию нужно ловить через $_GET (или $_POST), устанавливать вручную: session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']); а затем стартовать сессию: session_start();

Comment: До того как перешёл по ссылке и было "1 and 0",сейчас вернул с бэкапа  конф. файлы-"1 and 0",только как я уже писал выше толку всё равно 0!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Произвёл следующие изменения в коде и всё заработало:
    $s=session_id();
    header("Location: cabinet.php?PHPSESSID=$s");

Answer (score 1):

В cabinet.php пропишите `$a=session_name();print($a);print($_REQUEST[$a]);die()`. Что выводит?

Comment: Выводит PHPSESSID

Comment: Походу, у вас не проходит проверку $_REQUEST[session_name()]. Для чего она вообще?

Comment: Она для проверки того что Здесь норм проходит,а вот здесь
<br>if($_SESSION['usr_id'] == md5(crypt($_SESSION['login'],$_SESSION['pass'])))
<br>проверку не проходит.

Comment: Выводите промежуточные значения - это всегда полезно:  

    echo $_SESSION['usr_id'], '<br>', md5(crypt($_SESSION['login'],$_SESSION['pass']));

Comment: Как я и писал в вопросе не передаются значения ни $_SESSION['login'],ни $_SESSION['pass'],ни $_SESSION['usr_id'].

Comment: Читайте мой ответ в конце.

Comment: У меня ваш код работает как по нотам, в любом из вариантов: передача через Куки и через параметры $_GET

Answer (score 1):

еще группка трактористов :)

после header("Location: cabinet.php"); поставь exit ; и будет тебе счастье

Comment: Счастья не получилось(((

Answer (score 1):

Если

```
header("Location: cabinet.php"); exit;
```

срабатывает, с учетом того, что вообще до сюда доходит, то проблема либо в том что нет прав на запись в каталоге с ссесиями, что имхо маловероятно, но возможно, либо проблема уже в самом кабинете, а там 2 места:

если не срабатывает условие

```
if(isset($_REQUEST[session_name()]))
```

и вот тут вообще не понятно что (скобкЕ):

```
else
}
header("Location: auth.php");
}
```

после else не в ту сторону смотрит

Comment: Посмотрел в коде - скобка стоит правильно,здесь исправил...Сейчас проверю права

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема в

```
 session_start();
```

Указывайте всегда

```
 session_name("MyProject");
 session_start();
```

При таком синтаксисе будет привязка логина и пароля

Comment: еще для регистрации переменной в сессии лучше бы использовать 
session_register("User_name_id");
Но я ей никогда не пользуюсь так как иногда ошибки... Наверное просто не умею пользоваться...

Comment: указал не помогло...

Comment: указали на обоих страницах и с одинаковым именем?
задаете переменные через 
session_register()?

Comment: на обоих,с одинаковым,сейчас попробую session_register()

Comment: Ничего из выше предложенного не помогло...

Comment: Отмечу что подобная вещь прекрасно работает на другом серваке на FreeBSD,а вот на Debian какой то затык

Answer (score 0):

подождите...
А почему в форме регистрации не указан скрипт?

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<table>
    <tr><td>LOGIN</td> <td><input type="text" name="login"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>PASSWORD</td> <td><input type="password" name="pass"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2 align=center><input type="submit" name="sbm_auth" value="ENTER"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

должно быть вы забыли:

```
<form action="auth.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: Не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать session_start() в самом начале каждого файла

Comment: Безрезультатно,а какой в этом был скрытый смысл?Я просто чего то не догнал)

Answer (score -1):

```
if($_POST['sbm_auth'])
   {
   $login=($_POST['login']);
   $pass=($_POST['pass']);
```

Может стоит проверить их на пустоту?