# Регистрация и авторизация на сайте

Tags: php

Приветствую! Встал такой вопрос на пути к совершенству в php...
Вот сделал я дизайн страницы, сделал под нее верстку, теперь нужна регистрация, сделал регистрацию с мускулом с таблицей `users`, куда записываются все зареганные посетители, теперь встал вопрос, как сделать так, чтоб чтение шло из базы именно этой таблицы `users` и человек не авторизированный не мог видеть содержимое страницы? Какой код нужно разместить?

Что-то вроде этого `require_once("security_mod.php");` в начале главной страницы, а в файле `security_mod.php` содержимое будет таким :

```
<?php 
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Система авторизации HTTP-Basic авторизации
  // 2003-2005 (C) IT-студия SoftTime (http://www.softtime.ru)
  // Симдянов И.В. (simdyanov@softtime.ru)
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Устанавливаем соединение с базой данных
  require_once("config.php");
  // Если пользователь не авторизовался - авторизуемся
  if(!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) 
  { 
    Header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\""); 
    Header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); 
    exit(); 
  } 
  else 
  { 
    // Утюжим переменные $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] и $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'],
    // чтобы мышь не проскочила
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
      $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
      $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
    }
    $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = str_replace("'","`",$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = str_replace("'","`",$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);

    $query = "SELECT pass FROM userlist WHERE name='".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']."'";
    $lst = @mysql_query($query); 
    // Если ошибка в SQL-запросе - выдаём окно
    if(!$lst)
    {
      Header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\""); 
      Header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); 
      exit(); 
    }
    // Если такого пользователя нет - выдаём окно
    if(mysql_num_rows($lst) == 0)
    {
      Header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\""); 
      Header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); 
      exit(); 
    }
    // Если все проверки пройдены, сравниваем хэши паролей
    $pass = @mysql_fetch_array($lst);
    if(md5($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) != $pass['pass'])
    {
      Header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\""); 
      Header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); 
      exit(); 
    }
  }
?>
```

Вопрос в том, что мне не нравится этот тип запароливания сайта, там идет блокировка всего сайта, а не контента в частности... Мне нужно паролить часть сайта... Помогите...

Answer (score 1):

[как-закрыть-не-зарегистрированному-пользователю-страницу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/32656/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83)
[авторизация-в-php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/19115/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-php)
Обе ссылки доступны, если ввести в поиске авторизация.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так подключай только на той странице которая требуется, или впиши это в функцию
и вызывай на нужном месте и юзай ветвления, если не авторизирован тогда выдавать текст и форму входа
постом else
И пошел вывод контента

Comment: А да) переходи на $_SESSION['login']

Answer (score 0):

[4 урока по созданию регистрации на сайте на PHP + MySQL](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=369)

вот советую почитать написано все доступно и с примерами.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SESSION['login']) and !empty($_SESSION['password']))
{
//если существет логин и пароль в сессиях, то проверяем их и извлекаем аватар
$login = $_SESSION['login'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$classindex = "current_page_item";
//извлекаем нужные данные о пользователе
}
else {  // если не существет логин и пароль в сессиях, то отправляем на главную страницу
header('Location: /index.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделать переменную в сесии, к примеру $_SESSION['logging'], и при залогинивании юзверя выставлять её в 1. 
Дальше при выводе контента который ты хочеш закрыть просто проверять есть ли такая переменная и равна ли она единице. В итоге весь сайт будет доступен и без залогинивания, а нужная информация будет скрыта.